# set-language-environment and M-x shell

Tags: emacs, character-encoding

I am using shells using UTF-8 and others using Latin-1. However, when I change the default with `set-language-environment`, also the existing shells change their buffer-coding-system - indicator in the status-line.

How can I make a shell-buffer stick to its encoding?

Comment: Can you show us more of your setup? Would it be possible to make the changes be buffer local?

Comment: I am us this `set-language-environment` all the time between Latin-1 and UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LanguageEnvironment)? It has a tip on how to edit the ~/.emacs file:

> **Working around a broken LANG**
>
> If your LANG is not set up correctly, and you don’t want to fix it,
>   you can do the setup in your ~/.emacs file:
>
> ```
> (set-language-environment "Latin-1")
> ```
>
> Usually you would do it interactively: ‘C-x RET l’.
>
> To check the environment you want see ‘M-x
>   describe-language-environment’ and TAB to see all completions.

Comment: That's exactly what I do, but I want some Latin-1 shells and some UTF-8 ones.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52009/bash-shells-with-different-environment-variables), 
simply create a shell script such as e.g.`latinshell.sh` (adjust the desired variables):

```
#!/bin/sh
LANG=de_DE:Latin-1
```

and then run it in a shell with:

```
. latinshell.sh
```